# concatenar archivos y agregarles la fecha la cual se indica en su nombre

Tags: python, pandas

tengo este codigo para concatenar archivos .DAT, pero me interesa crearles una columna fecha, la cual corresponde al nombre del archivo: por ejemplo

`MX010105.DAT`
`MX010205.DAT`
`MX010305.DAT` , los archivos en su estructura no traen fecha entonces quiero agregarles la columna fecha y poner la fecha que está en su nombre por ejemplo: `01/01/2005`

````
Header2 = ['Lon', 'Lat', 'Pre', 'Est']
dtypes = {'Lon': 'object'}

df=dd.read_csv('Z:/ihernandez/Artur/Estaciones_ftp_200_4_8_36/Lluvias/2014/*.DAT',sep = "\t",header = None,names = Header2,
                  encoding = "latin-1", dtype = dtypes)

computed_df = df.compute()
computed_df.to_csv("Z:/ihernandez/Artur/Estaciones_ftp_200_4_8_36/2014.csv",sep = ",") ```
````

Comment: Puedes agregar más info a tu pregunta, la información actual que muestra y lo que quieres lograr.

Comment: Sí, tengo archivos.DAT por cada año, del 2005 al 2019, quiero concatenarlos y tener una sola base de datos, el problema es que estos archivos requieren una columna con la fecha y no la tienen, entonces sería agregar la fecha, la cual es corresponde al nombre del archivo.

Comment: a mano sería: abrir archivo.DAT agregar columna con nombre fecha, utilizar fileName = os.path.splitext(MM) para sacar el nombre y data.loc[:, 'fecha'] = nombre para agregarlo a la columna con formato dd,mm,aaaa, para cada archivo y guardarlos con la misma extensión para después concatenarlos

Comment: Ivan, ¿podrías indicar la estructura interna de tus archivos .dat, por favor? Por lo que describes, el contenido de tu archivo corresponde a un archivo separado por tabulaciones.

Comment: RodrigoN! claro, cuando abro el archivo en excel me salen 4 columnas con sus respectivas líneas :                                                    -102.427778  21.916944 0 ABRAG
-102.309722 21.895         0 AGSAG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iván, cambié algunas cosas del ejemplo que diste. 
Creé dos archivos separados por tabulación:

MX010205.csv

```
-1.427778   21.916944   0   ABRAG
-2.309722   22.895  0   AGSAG
```

MX010206.csv

```
-3.427778   23.916944   0   ABRAG
-4.309722   24.895  0   AGSAG
```

Cambié el valor de cada primer número (de tu ejemplo), para que fuera más claro. Y escribí el siguiente código:

```
import pandas as pd
from os import listdir

cabeceras = ['Lon', 'Lat', 'Pre', 'Est', 'Fecha']
dtypes = {'Lon': 'object'}
lectura = pd.DataFrame()

for archivo_csv in listdir():
  if archivo_csv[-3:].lower() == "csv":
    lectura = pd.concat([lectura, pd.read_csv(archivo_csv, sep="\t", header=None, dtype=dtypes,
                                               names=cabeceras, encoding = "latin-1")])
    lectura["Fecha"] = archivo_csv[3:-4]


lectura.to_csv("resultado.csv", sep="\t", header=None, index=None)
```

Modifiqué la variable que contiene la cabecera, agregando "Fecha", al final.

Con **listdir()** leo el contenido del directorio actual (metí los csv dentro de un directorio, junto con el archivo .py, para simplificar el ejemplo), y me traigo todos los archivos, luego el **if** a continuación, **archivo_csv[-3:].lower() == "csv"**,evalúa que la extensión del archivo leído sea csv.

Después, **pd.concat()**, une el dataframe *lectura*, con la lectura realizada con **pd.read_csv()**, del archivo actual.

Con **lectura["Fecha"]** indico que voy a agregar datos a la columna y con **archivo_csv[3:-4]**, recorto del nombre del archivo actual, lo que me parece que corresponde a la fecha que quieres incluir.

Finalmente **lectura.to_csv("resultado.csv", sep="\t", header=None, index=None)**, guarda los cambios en un nuevo archivo, con el atributo **index=None**, para que no almacene los índices de las filas.

Por favor, revisa el código y ve si es que se adapta a lo que necesitas.

Comment: Hola RodrigoN, revise el código y al correrlo si me concatena, solo que no me pone los títulos de las columnas y en la columna fecha me pone la palabra resultado: Est Fecha Lat Lon Pre
0 AHLTP ultado 22.988611 -98.145 0.0
1 AGSAG ultado 21.895000 -102.309722 0.0
2 ANVAG ultado 22.188611 -102.466944 0.0
3 BRTAG ultado 21.738611 -102.184167 0.0
4 COCGR ultado 18.245278 -99.661944 0.0

Comment: (archivo_csv) está guardando el nombre y extensión con que se va a guardar el archivo resultante, en este caso "resultado.csv"

Comment: ahora con esto que cambie me pone la misma fecha 311205

lst = glob.glob("*.dat")
for archivo_csv in lst:
    if archivo_csv[-3:].lower() == "dat":

Comment: Iván, para que aparezcan los nombres de las columnas, quita el *header=None*, al guardar.

Comment: ya se lo quite y ya salen los nombres, ahora me falta que salga la fecha, me pone la del 311205, osea la ultima en todos las filas de fecha

Comment: hago un print(archivo_csv) antes de pd.read y pd.concat y si me da la lista completa de los archivos, que podrá ser?

Comment: El for lo estás haciendo por el nombre del archivo, verdad? Quizas sería bueno que actualices la pregunta con el código que has ido modificando, para poder probarlo sin hacer suposiciones sobre tu avance.

Comment: si, para eso es el for, aun que no se de que otra forma lo puedo hacer. en cuanto a lo de actualizar la pregunta como le hago?

Comment: Justo abajo de la pregunta que formulaste, hay un enlace que dice "editar".